# Dominion remodel card -can I trash a card already played?

Tags: dominion

Can you trash a card that you have already played, when remodelling? E.g. I play a village, then a Worksop, then Remodel - trashing the Workshop I just played? It says from your hand, but am unclear if there is a distinction between hand and play.

Answer (score 22):

No, you cannot do this. Your "hand" always refers to cards that you physically keep in your hand. Cards that you have played this turn are in a different place, the "in-play" area.

On page 6 of [the rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=348):

> To play an Action, the player takes an Action card from his hand
>   and lays it face-up in his play area.

Pages 9 and 10 also show picture examples of the different places cards might be; including hand, deck, discard, or in-play.

Answer (score 4):

If you have played the card, then it is on the table, not in your hand.

Comment: The rules (including card text) call this "in play" - see for example Peddler.